# How do I implement cache busting for my frontend application that uses cloudfront CDN?

Tags: webpack, caching, frontend, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

**Context**

I've seen a recurring problem when creating a new release, which is twofold, and it relates to caching.

The first scenario is when I post a new release to my frontend client and a supposed keeps getting served old code. That seems to be an issue with the CDN cache. After some research, I discovered that one could leverage [webpack caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) in conjunction with the [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to solve this issue.

The second scenario, however, is a bit different. If a user has left their device open and the browser does not perform an automatic reload, then the user will be using old code, even if a release has happened and we use the above solution. I arrived at a sub-optimal solution that performs a periodic check to the CDN, say every 10 minutes, to look for a new version (new webpack build hash). If a new version is found, then a popup appears and the user is forced to reload.

**Question**

I'm trying to understand how to implement that periodic check. So far, I've read up a bit on [cloudfront functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html), but I'm having a hard time understanding how to make cloudfront extract the relevant information, or whether there might be a much simpler solution for what  I'm trying to achieve.